# ColdFusion Not Recognizing TIFF MIME type?

Tags: coldfusion, upload, mime, tiff, cffile

Coldfusion 8, Apache, Mac OS X Server 10.5.

I have a web application which lets users upload images. However, it always fails to upload TIFF files. JPEG, GIF, and PNG upload just fine, this problem seems to be only with TIFFs.

The user selects the image to upload via a cfinput tag in a form. When the form is submitted, I try to rename and move the file using a cfimage tag. For JPEGs, PNGs, etc. this works perfectly, but if the image is a TIFF, it errors out to:

**"ColdFusion was unable to create an image from the specified source file. Ensure that the file is a vaild image file."**

Next I changed the cfimage tag to a cffile tag to try a different way to rename and move the uploaded image, but that gives the error:

**"The MIME type of the uploaded file video/x-ms-wm was not accepted by the server. Only files of type image/* can be uploaded."**

So, it seems that ColdFusion thinks TIFFs are videos. I doubled checked /Applications/ColdFusion8/runtime/lib/mime.types, and that contains

**image/tiff                      tiff tif**

...just like it ought to. Why can't ColdFusion get TIFFs' MIME type right?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you check to see if video/x-ms-wm was in there?  I checked mine and it is not.

Comment: Regarding the cfimage error - are they multi-page tiffs? I do not think cfimage supports those.

Answer (score 3):

The MIME type of an uploaded file is provided by the browser which means it is not reliable.

You did not provide any code samples, but I am guessing you are using the *accepts* attribute in your  tag. Try removing that and see if things work as expected.

Using the *accepts* attribute is not a reliable way of determining if a file is of a certain type, since it is provided by the browser it cannot be trusted. Instead, you should be looking at the extension, and if you really want to be secure, using an inspection utility to examine the file and make sure it is what the extension says it is.

You can read more about his on Pete Freitag's blog. http://www.petefreitag.com/item/701.cfm

Answer (score 1):

From the [CF 9 release notes](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/coldfusion/9/cf9_releasenotes.pdf):

> 79685
>      CFIMAGE
>
> On Mac OS X Snow Leopard, `cfimage` tag does not support TIFF images for read/write operation though `getReadableImageFormats` and `getWriteableImageFormats` list TIFF as a supported image format.